# can't authentic user but credentials are correct in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-authentication

I have the following login form:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    remember_session = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(LoginForm, self).clean()
        email = cleaned_data.get('email')
        password = cleaned_data.get('password')
        if email and password:
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(email=email)
                if not user.check_password(password):
                    raise forms.ValidationError('Credentials do not match.')
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                raise forms.ValidationError('Customer does not exist.')
        return cleaned_data
```

Here is my view code:

```
if request.method == "POST":
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            remember_session = form.cleaned_data['remember_session']
            if remember_session:
                request.session.set_expiry(0)
            user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['email'], password=form.cleaned_data['password'])
            print user
            if user:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect(next)
            else:
                print 'something went wrong'
```

This prints:

> user: None
>
> something went wrong

How could this pass the check_password in the form but not find a user in authentic?

Comment: `authenticate` Check the username/password and return a User, but your code `username=form.cleaned_data['email']` so for doing that you need specify custom backend https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/ you can use this one https://github.com/dabapps/django-email-as-username/blob/master/emailusernames/backends.py

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was changing the user email, but logging in basedon the user's username which was the email.  This caused the discrepancy.